# Encrypted/Password protected zip directories in java

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption, password-protection, password-encryption

I am interested in finding out how it is possible to encrypt/password protect directories (i.e. folder) using Java. Thus I would like to be able to specify a particular directory (located in my Eclipse workspace), a password and then be able to zip/archive that directory and password protect it such that it cannot be accessed unless entering the password. How is this possible?

Comment: I think it's not on Java API but some people did it like: http://java.sys-con.com/node/1258827. You could also more simply just call zip command line on desired directory with the encryption option -e and the password  you want to set

Comment: when I run the zip command with the encryption, how come I am then able to unzip the created zip by double clicking on it in the file system. It doesnt ask me to enter a password

Comment: Under mac os, it ask me the password. May be depends on your zip tool . What is the default zip utility for you ? Can you unzip it with command line ?

Comment: looks like it works now. Is there a platform independent way of achieving this? Since windows doesnt support zip command line

Comment: on windows you can look at http://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili to get the command line. The platform independent way is to do every thing in Java like my first link